# Adding a dependency in android project

Tags: android, textview, dependencies

eg.

```
`dependencies {
compile 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.+'
}`
```

Where do i add this and how to make it work? i am trying to incorporate autofit textview in android

Comment: You have to add this to your `build.gradle` file. (Assuming that you're using Android Studio)

Comment: no i was actually using eclipse i haven't migrated to android studio yet

Comment: You should have added this to your question. With Eclipse you can't use a gradle dependency, you have to import the corresponding library as a library-project to your workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Find the `build.gradle` for your project, add the `compile` statement to the existing lines in the `dependencies` section. Android Studio will prompt you to "Sync Gradle Project Files", which will trigger everything required to find the library. After the sync you'll be able to import and use the classes as required.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this then you need to have an Build-Management Tool like Maven, Ant or Gradle. Then this Tool downloads the dependacys for you.
But if you dont have something like this then just add this file to the project:
http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/me/grantland/autofittextview/0.2.0/autofittextview-0.2.0-sources.jar